# How to periodically re-render a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For a reason I will not explain here, I have a react component which I need to re-render every time it finishes rendering, without exceeding the maximum render stack depth.

I have tried setting some state inside my of `useEffect` listener to force the component to re-render, but it keeps exceeding the maximum stack size.

Is there another way?

Comment: That sounds like a performance nightmare and is probably the wrong solution to [your real problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like:

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(Date.now());

useEffect(() => {
    let requestId;
    const update = () => {
        setTime(Date.now());
        requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    update();
    return () => {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
    };
}, []);
```

This way you trigger an update every time the browser is about to do another repaint (so not "immediately" but it will feel like it).  And it's not going to create a huge stack.

As a side note, you don't want to pass anything inside []. If you pass `time` in the brackets, it means run the effect every time the value of time changes, i.e., which is not what we're looking for.  It already is a "loop", so we only need it to run once on mount, and then clear the update loop when the component is unmounted.